# Basic adding multiplying subtracting Python maths

Tags: python, int, sum, addition

So i want to have a user input a number using

```
input = raw_input ("What is your number")
```

and then this number lets say 5 has the following operations completed

```
result = input + 3 then * 2 then - 4 then - (2 * input) then + 3
```

so with my example of 5 the following would be the chain of maths

```
5 : 8 : 16 : 12 : 2 : 5
```

and finally a print statement of

```
print "Your answer is: " + result
```

I am doing this all in terminal on my mac and using nano as a text editor, I have tried multiple ways such as assigning every single number to a variable later and then only using letters and of course the obvious way of just plugging the numbers in but I always get an error.

Here is one of the sections of code I have tried

```
    #!usr/bin/env

a = 6
b = 3
c = 2
d = 4

sum = ((((a + b) * c) - d)( - ( c * a )) + b)

print sum
```

then saving the file as a .py file and the whole chmod +x filename.py then python filename.py and always an error, for the example above i get

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: Aren't you missing an operator... _((((a + b) * c) - d) **HERE?** ( - ( c * a )) + b)_

Comment: Python thinks `(expression1)(expression2)` is a call of `expression1` with arguments `expression2`, if you need a multiplication use `(expression1) * (expression2)`. Probably a typo.

Comment: don't use `sum` or `input` as a variable names or that will be another question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break down this exception: TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
'callable' means you tried to invoke a function (or call a method) on an object which does not support it (an object which is not a function). In this case it says 'int'.

The equation in your code resolves from left to right as you probably know, so the left set of parentheses: ((((a + b) * c) - d) produces an integer (14), the right set also produces an int.
And the problem, as people before me have mentioned, is that you forgot the operator (*) which instead of this: 14 * (-9), resulted in something like this: 14(-9), which is the correct syntax if you are trying to call a function named 14 with the parameter -9.

Answer (score 1):

```
sum = ((((a + b) * c) - d)( - ( c * a )) + b)
                          ^ You need an operation to occur here before the parenthesis
```

You missed an arithmetic symbol in your equation.

Right now, it is trying to call a function with the name of the first have of your equation.